# Xcode storyboard elements showing as white rather than blue

Tags: ios, xcode

Sorry if the title doesn't explain the issue properly.

In all tutorials I see, a UIImageView, for example, has a blue background on storyboards. (Refer to below)

[image]

Whereas mine looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, guys, I solved it, if anyone else is having this issue, here's how to fix it.

Editor > Canvas > Show Placeholder Backgrounds

[image: Editor > Canvas > Show Placeholder Backgrounds]

Comment: Interestingly, I have to close and reopen the storyboard to make this change take effect.

Comment: Yeah rob, I had to move the effected elements by 1 pixel